# Settings of Virtual Environment in Python with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I tried but completely failed to find any useful info on this particular subject on the internet.

I am a beginner in Django.  I installed "virtualenv" with pip, and created an environment under "D:\Dropbox\Git\Python\Django_projects" called "env_mysite."

In the Command Prompt, everything works as expected.  But now, since I tried to code with Visual Studio Code, I would like to use "Ctrl+Shift+P" to quickly select python interpreter, which in my case would be either the "normal python" or the one in the virtual environment in the D: path aforementioned... it depends on the project.

After googling, I understand it seems that this may be because of the wrong path settings in the User Settings in VS Code.

My current path settings are as below:

[python.venvPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djwdR.png) and 
[python.pythonPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwrLD.png).

I hope some of you guys can help me with how to set the correct path under Windows.

Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is under `D:\Dropbox\Git\Python\Django_projects` and `env_mysite` is the only virtual environment, then open the `Django_projects` folder in VS Code and the Python extension will simply discover your virtual environment.

If your code lives elsewhere then you will want to set `"python.pythonPath": "D:\\Dropbox\\Git\\Python\\Django_projects\\Scripts\\python.exe"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brett! Took me days to understand how this works.